Convert number in excel to M or B
How can to convert numbers in Excel to hundred normal and (K) to thousand and (M) to Milion and (B) to Billion
like the below

and i used this format but give all hundred number with (K)
\[\<100000\]0.00,"K";\[\<100000000\]0.00,,"M";0.00,,,"B"


i need formating like the below image


Just as Ron suggested, using conditional formatting would keep the value as number.

Reset formatting: select the range where you have applied your custom formatting and change it to General. This may be why nothing changed when you applied the conditional formatting.

Apply conditional formatting (Menu > Format > Conditional Formatting) as here (using your excellent format code :)

Add new rule (press +)
Choose Classic > Format only cells that contain > Cell Value > Greater than or equal to
Enter 1000
Format with > Custom Format - enter your format code
Applies to: Enter the range containing the numbers.





Regular number formatting can only have three numerical sections, and you need four.
The first two answers turn the numbers into text strings.
To retain the values as numbers, you can use conditional formatting.
For example: Applying the format to column A


Rule for 1: NumberFormat = [<1000]0.00;#,##0.00,K
Rule for 2: NumberFormat = [>999999999]0.00,,,\B;[>999999]0.00,,\M

Or something similar


can you please more description, i tried to apply but nothing changed.

@user25863538 I'm not at my computer right now. However, you can read about conditional formatting using a formula in the Microsoft help topic for that subject.

@user25863538 Try looking at this video where I show one method to enter conditional formatting for column A.

Here is one alternative formula using MAP():


=MAP(A1:A7, LAMBDA(Σ,
 LET(α,SUM(--(Σ>=10^{3,6,9})),
 IF(α,TEXT(LEFT(Σ/("1e"&α*3),4),"0.00 ")
 &MID("KMB",α,1),Σ))))


use this formula in excel:
=IF(A1>=1000000000, TEXT(A1/1000000000, "0.0") & "B", IF(A1>=1000000, TEXT(A1/1000000, "0.0") & "M", A1))


Select Your Range
use Ctrl+1 to show format cells dialog
click on "custom"
in the "type" box type:

    #,##
    (123456789000  >>  123,456,789,000)
    #,##,
    (123456789000 >> 123,456,789)
    #,##, "K"
    (123456789000 >> 123,456,789 K)
    #,##,,
    (123456789000 >> 123,456)
    #,##,, "M"
    (123456789000 >> 123,456 M)
    #,##,,,
    (123456789000 >> 123)
    #,##,,, "B"
    (123456789000 >> 123 B)



I tried to follow your instructions but am not able to enter that string as a number format in Excel. Nor have I ever seen that type of formatting documented before. Are you sure you are writing about Excel?

Hi @RonRosenfeld , yes it is about excel. I inserted a picture above and show how to use formatting cells

That's not what you wrote to type. And if you do what your picture shows, you'll need to set the format individually instead of having it set automatically depending on the value.
